# ¿Como mostrar los valores de todos los input tipo radio que tengan la misma clase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Quiero obtener todos los valores de los input tipo radio para  luego compararlo con una variable con un valor puesto y si algunos de esos input tipo radio coincide  con el valor de esa variable  me seleccione ese  input tipo radio

He estado intentado obteniendo la cantidad de input tipo radio que tengan la misma clase y luego mostrar en un alert el valor de esos input para luego compararlos con el valor de una variable  pero  solo me muestra el valor del primer input. 
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Como puedo hacer que cuando un valor de todos esos radios sea igual que el valor var zona= "B3"; se active?

- Ya pude hacer que active el radio con el valor indicado 
  Use el ejemplo de KIKO_L  y puse esto en lugar del alertar :
  $(this).attr('checked', true);

```js
var zona = "B3";
$(".zona").each(function() {
if($(this).val() === zona)
{
 $(this).attr('checked', true);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" id="modalAddPermiso" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="examplehttps://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/159707/edit#ModalLabel">Asignación de Permisos por Paginas</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="form_permiso" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                <label for="Zona">Zona</label>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="zona"  name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A1" >A1
                    </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A2">A2
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A3" >A3
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A4" >A4
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A5" >A5
                  </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B1" >B1
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B2">B2
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B3" >B3
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B4" >B4
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B5" >B5
                </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C1" >C1
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C2">C2
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C3" >C3
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
              <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonahttps://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/159707/edit#E" id="zonaE" value="C4" >C4
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C5" >C5
              </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="btnsavepermiso">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `for` no para porque tienes puesto `i = nradios` como condición de parada en el for (en vez de `i<=nradios`). Además, al hacer var `valorradio = $(".zona").val();` estás asignado a `valorradio` siempre el valor del primer `radiobutton` (A1).

La mejor manera de iterar con `jQuery` es utilizando `each`. Utiliza el selector de clases para obtener todos los elementos con clase `zona` y luego itera por ellos con `each`:

```js
var zona = "B3";
$(".zona").each(function() {
if($(this).val() === zona)
{
 alert('Este (' + $(this).val() + ') es el radio B3');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" id="modalAddPermiso" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asignación de Permisos por Paginas</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="form_permiso" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                <label for="Zona">Zona</label>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="zona"  name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A1" >A1
                    </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A2">A2
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A3" >A3
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A4" >A4
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="A5" >A5
                  </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B1" >B1
                  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B2">B2
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B3" >B3
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B4" >B4
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="B5" >B5
                </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C1" >C1
                </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C2">C2
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C3" >C3
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
              <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C4" >C4
              </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="zona" name="zonaE" id="zonaE" value="C5" >C5
              </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="btnsavepermiso">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Más info sobre [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Muchas gracias Kiko_L, pero ahora como ago  para que ese input con ese valor se quede   marcada ? intente poner   $(".zona").attr('checked', true);  pero me marca el ultimo input

Comment: Ya pude hacer que active el input  puse esto en vez del alerta :  $(this).attr('checked', true);